# Xamarin.forms socket.io client

Tags: c#, xamarin, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a socket.io client in Xamarin.forms for iOS and Android.

All solutions I've found are deprecated. The last came out is from [IBM](https://github.com/IBM/socket-io) but seems abandoned too, and lacks of documentation.

Anybody was able to make socket.io client works on Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to connect : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO

Comment: Yes jdweng, it's a popular open source project born before websocket diffusion: https://socket.io/.
My next commitment is to try https://github.com/mattleibow/Socket.IO.Client

Comment: I found the GitHub link yesterday but wanted to make sure it was what you needed before providing the link.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler if you have issues to help debug.

Comment: I've got some tips from Microsoft insider to try also https://www.nuget.org/packages/Socket.IO.Client, but it seems Android only